# How to do inner join on different db tables in springboot jpa

Tags: inner-join, spring-boot-jpa

I want to implement below query using springboot jpa,Is it possible??

```
    select * from 
    Claims.misuser.CLXMstApplicationRole AR WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
    PADB.misuser.clxmstaccesspermission AP WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
    AP.intApplicationRoleId = AR.intApplicationRoleId 
    where AR.txtApplicationRoleCode = 'CRUAPP'
```

I have written below code in my repository Interface

```
@Query(value=QueryConstants.InnerJoin_AppRole_AccessPermission)
List<ApplicationRole> findBy_InnerJoin_AppRole_AccessPermission();
```

QueryConstants.java

```
 InnerJoin_AppRole_AccessPermission="select AR FROM com.infosys.claims.broadband.springboot.entity.claims.ApplicationRole AR "+
                                                                  "INNER JOIN com.infosys.claims.broadband.springboot.entity.padb.AccessPermission AP"+
                                                                  "ON AR.applicationRole = AP.applicationRoleId" + 
                                                                  "where AR.applicationRoleCode = 'CRUAPP' ";
```

But this gives me empty list, In mssql, it gives me records.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the query as it is.**

```
@Query(value = "select * from 
    Claims.misuser.CLXMstApplicationRole AR WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
    PADB.misuser.clxmstaccesspermission AP WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
    AP.intApplicationRoleId = AR.intApplicationRoleId 
    where AR.txtApplicationRoleCode = (?1)", nativeQuery = true)
List<ApplicationRole> findBy_InnerJoin_AppRole_AccessPermission(ApplicationRoleCode crudApp);
```

Just set the value of variable `crudApp` as `"CRUAPP"`.

`,nativeQuery = true)`  in the above code makes it very easy if u have faith on your queries!